# Как добавить в словарь элементы другого словаря в python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, словари

помогите плиз разобраться.. делаю бота с клавиатурой вконтакте. хочу сделать динамически обновляемую клавиатуру чтобы в зависимости от количества записей в бд появлялось ровно столько кнопок сколько и товаров. Но когда я делаю, то в логах вижу ошибку

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'dict'

мой код ниже.

```
cursor.execute('select id_product FROM gxvg_inventory WHERE vk_id =  (%s) ' + limit + '', (user))
res = cursor.fetchall()
# print(type(res))
if res:
    keyboard = {}

    for id_product in res:
        keyboard += {
                      "inline": True,
                      "buttons": [
                        [{
                          "action": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "payload": id_product,
                            "label": "Использовать"
                          },
                          "color": "positive"
                        },
                          {
                            "action": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "payload": "{\"button\": \"12002\"}",
                              "label": "Положить"
                            },
                            "color": "primary"
                        },
                          {
                            "action": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "payload": json.dumps({'buttons': 12000 + 3}),
                              "label": "Продать"
                            },
                            "color": "negative"
                          }],
                        [{
                          "action": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "payload": json.dumps({'buttons': 12000 + 4}),
                            "label": "Далее >>"
                          },
                          "color": "secondary"
                        }]
                      ]
                    }
    print(keyboard)
    keyboard = json.dumps(keyboard, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
    keyboard = str(keyboard.decode('utf-8'))
    return keyboard
```

без цикла for клавиатура создается вот в таком виде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а мне необходимо сделать что-то подобное..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Третий день бьюсь с этой клавиатурой, и уже подумываю о том чтобы передавать элементы клавиатуры как-то статично, подставляя свои значения из базы данных, но это уже костыль..

я даже пытался объединять несколько заранее подготовленных словарей в один, но это кошмар.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно не "складывать" словари, а добавлять новые кнопки в список, потом записать их по ключу `"buttons"`:

```
buttons = []

for id_product in res:
    # Добавить ряд кнопок
    buttons.append([
        {
            "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "payload": id_product,
                "label": "Использовать"
            },
            "color": "positive"
        },
        {
            "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "payload": "{\"button\": \"12002\"}",
                "label": "Положить"
            },
            "color": "primary"
        },
        {
            "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "payload": json.dumps({'buttons': 12000 + 3}),
                "label": "Продать"
            },
            "color": "negative"
        }
    ])

# Добавить кнопку "далее" в самом конце после цикла
buttons.append([{
    "action": {
        "type": "text",
        "payload": json.dumps({'buttons': 12000 + 4}),
        "label": "Далее >>"
    },
    "color": "secondary"
}])

keyboard = {"inline": True, "buttons": buttons}
```

По поводу "сложения" словарей: можно обновлять данные словаря из другого словаря с помощью метода `update`, но при этом данные по одному и тому же ключу перезапишутся.

Нет такого специального "волшебного" метода, который понимал бы, что ключ-значение `"inline": True` не нужно трогать, а в список по ключу `"buttons"` нужно добавлять данные из другого словаря, а не перезаписывать.

Comment: У меня сейчас чавка отвалилась! Спасибо Вам огромное за столь подробный ответ! всё по полочкам разложили просто мне:) за одно пойду на будущее перечитаю как работать со словарями в питоне)) Благодарю Вас!

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы пытаетесь добавить что-то в словарь, подразумевается, что это будет пара key : value, вы же пытаетесь передать в словарь другой словарь (который не может являться ключом).